# "a part of" vs "part of"

Tags: articles

[thefreedictionary.com](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/The-Predicate.htm):

> “*When my father is home on the weekends, the whole family always goes to a movie together*.”
> The dependent clause has the subject "*my father*", and the predicate is "*is home on the weekends*". The dependent clause is linked to the independent clause by the subordinating conjunction "*when*", which can also be considered **part** of the dependent clause’s predicate. The subject of the independent clause is "*the whole family*", and the predicate is "*always goes to a movie together*".

Why is it possible to write "*part*" without an article?
I can only understand if there were "***a** part of the dependent clause’s predicate*" meaning "*one of parts of the dependent clause’s predicate*".

---

Looking at similar threads on this site and on others, I could find the only one explanation on this topic. It is best expressed [here](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/it-is-a-part-of.1211731/post-7159375):

> *A is part of B*. – A is integral to B, A and B are indivisible
> *A is **a** part of B*. – B consists of a number of components, one of which is A

According to this explanation, only my version (with "**a** part of") is correct:
["*when*", which can also be considered **part** of the dependent clause’s predicate] — incorrect because the dependent clause’s predicate consists of several different components ("when", "is", "home", "on the weekends") and "*when*" is just one of them
["*when*", which can also be considered **a part** of the dependent clause’s predicate] — correct

Comment: Did you search "is part of" and "is a part of" (in Google Books, for example) to see how those strings are actually used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source you quoted about the difference between the two forms is at least half right, in that "a part of" has a meaning similar to "a section of", where there's some kind of division in something that's not uniform. So if you're talking about something uniform, like a chicken breast, "a part of" is incorrect semantically:

> Part of this chicken breast is undercooked.
> <del>A part of this chicken breast is undercooked.</del>

As far as I can tell though, *the reverse is not true*. That's to say, I can't think of a context where it's incorrect to use "part of" to refer to a distinct portion of something non-uniform.

> They only painted part of the car.
> Part of the factory isn't getting power.
> Part of my family lives in Europe.

This means there's apparently no rule against using "part of" when describing a part of something divisible, like a single word in a dependent clause's predicate.

Comment: If we add an adjective to "_part of this chicken breast_", which of the variants is correct? For example, with the article: "_**A large** part of this chicken breast_"; and without the article: "_**Large** part of this chicken breast_"? Thanks.

Comment: With an adjective, we either need "a", or "parts" must be plural. Since neither applies properly to an indivisible chicken breast, we'd probably say "***a lot of** this chicken breast...*"